# Difference between acid-catalysed iodination of acetone and the iodoform reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry

I am curious about what makes the iodoform reaction (in alkaline conditions) substitute 3 times whereas the iodination of propanone (acidic conditions) only substitutes once. Or am I just completely misinformed regarding this and the acid catalysed reaction can actually substitute multiple times? Thanks a lot from a student who is just very curious about why in this reactions the acidic or alkaline conditions can change the reaction so much.